# iPhone background app showing Call alert

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I am new to iPhone programming and I have a question. If I have an application that needs to initiate a phone call at 11:00 AM, is it possible for the app to show a call alert to the user? so the user at 11 would see the number pop up with a call or cancel option. Thoughts? Also is this also possible if my app is not running in the background and If I have to initiate using push notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using a [local notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that will bring your application to foreground (well, sort of, an alert will be displayed that will allow the user to take the appropriate action).

In order to launch a phone call you are going to use the [openURL method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728) on the application object like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:12345689"]];
```

Comment: Using this method, is it possible to show the phone number itself as the alert or do I need to show an alert , launch the app and then present the user with an option to call?

Comment: You get your own choice what text to show when displaying the alert to the user. However, when you will initiate the call (via openURL) another alert will be shown to the user saying "Call +123456789 ? [YES] [NO]". You can't control this last alert, but you can control the others.